# Install apk via adb can not delete old apk

Tags: android

I try to install via adb an apk to a connected device with :

`adb -d install android-debug.apk`

But could not delete the old apk :

`2956 KB/s (2131317 bytes in 0.704s)
        pkg: /data/local/tmp/android-debug.apk
Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_ALREADY_EXISTS]
rm failed for -f, No such file or directory`

is there a way to force the install ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`adb install -r android-debug.apk`

`-r` replaces the existing APK.

I know, it is [**not** documented](https://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html)... but the command's `--help` lists:

```
adb install [-lrtsd] <file> - push this package file to the device and install it
                             (-l: forward lock application)
                             (-r: replace existing application)
                             (-t: allow test packages)
                             (-s: install application on sdcard)
                             (-d: allow version code downgrade)
                             (-p: partial application install)
```

Comment: Thank you @shkschneider it works the reponse was : `Success` it should be documented.

Comment: It should. I edited my answer with the output of `adb --help` that exposes this (sadly undocumented) option.

Comment: use -d -r together in case you need to downgrade apk version code (install apk with lower version code)